# SSRS Change Parameter Values In Each Cell

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, expression, where-clause

In SSRS I am trying to set parameter values in each given cell.  For example I have the parameters @Code, @StatusID, @AnalysisID.

The @Code is set at the beginning of the report like usual but I have sums and counts in the report where in different cells I will need to say

```
Fields!fieldname.value where @StatusID = 1 and @AnalysisID =2.
```

The next cell would be 
`Fields!fieldname.value where @statusID = 1 and @AnalysisID = 3`
 for example.

Is it even possible to change parameters through expression boxes like this?  If so what is the syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.   Is it something like this?:   IIF(Parameters!StatusID=1 AND Parameters!AnalysisID=2, Fields!fieldname.value,Nothing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at the [expressions of ssrs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx).From what I understood you want to set the value of cell depending on the parameter values

so for the first cell expression

```
  = IIF(Parameters!StatusID=1 AND Parameters!AnalysisID=2, Fields!fieldname.value,Nothing)
```

and For the second cell expression

```
  = IIF(Parameters!StatusID=1 AND Parameters!AnalysisID=3, Fields!fieldname.value,Nothing)
```

Comment: The exact opposite actually.  I wanted each cell to be able to change the value of the parameter then run the query with that parameter and return the value in the cell.  I found a way around this by designing the sql query better on the back end.